# Time complexity of this 2 loop algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

How do I understand the time complexity of this algorithm? It came up during an interview and I thought it was O(n^2) but my interviewer said it was O(nlogn).

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=i; j<n; j++) {
        if (A[i] + B[j] = 100) {
            return i, j;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implementation is indeed O(n^2), the inner loop only saves half of the counting, but a different version could be created O(n log n) by just sorting and a linear iteration.
Given the constant number of 100, there are even linear versions. O(n*100)

Comment: Maybe it was more like a personality test ;)